# I would like to get the names of cities with highest number of reviews where the State is Unique

Tags: mysql, sql

To better phrase that question. This is what I want my query to do:
" SELECT a CITY with the highest number of reviews WHERE the State is unique" --> translated to From Every State in the US give me one city that has the highest number of reviews. So I should end up with a total of 50 rows.

Here is what my table looks like.

[image: Table Columns Sample]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this with a `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.numreviewspercity = (select max(t2.numreviewspercity)
                             from t t2
                             where t2.state = t.state
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace table with actual table name :

select city from table t where t.NumReviewperCity = (select max(NumReviewperCity) from table where state=t.state);